# Resetting new password matches old password

Tags: passwords, md5, reset, password-encryption

I need to understand if we don't store actual password in our database because of security reason. We normally store one-way encrypted passwords. Now if this is true, and we wan't to change the password how does some of the well known web-sites figure out that new password is very close or partially matching old password and they prompt us to change it. For that to happen they will have to store old password somewhere or two way encrypted password which could be decrypted again.

Comment: The real issue here is poor password rules. By making users change their password periodically you are ensuring the users will have poor passwords and more likely write them on "posit" notes. The new NIST proposed rules (800-63-3: Digital Authentication Guidelines) callout this as a practice that should not be done. Dont: 1. Require composition rules 2. Allow hints 3. Require routine password expiration.  See [New Password Rules](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/). OTOH your organization may be more interested in using failed practices.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. Normally when you change your password, you are first required to type in your old password to confirm that you are you.  The site could be temporarily keeping that old password in memory so that it can compare your old password to your new one.
2. When you type in your new password, it can be checking if the hash of number of simple modifications to it maps to the hash of your old password.

For example, if you type in your new password as "password7", then the site may be doing a number of checks such as the following:

```
password_hash( "password0", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password1", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password2", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password3", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password4", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password5", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password6", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password7", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password8", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
password_hash( "password9", old_salt ) == value stored in database?
```

This would be really, really slow if they used a proper password hashing algorithm (such as bcrypt or scrypt), but I would not be surprised if this is actually done in some implementations.

Of course, there is also the third possibility that the stupid website never hashed your password in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for the logical answer. But this seems to be a highly probabilistic approach. How to determine the anagrams of the new password. Also the closest anagram e.g, password6 's hash might be very different than password7 's hash OR 7password 's hash. If this is so, I would then again think the question is still open.